# How to Add new items to existing items in a checkbox list

Tags: c#, addition, checkboxlist

I am new to .net, Here i had two checkbox lists lets say a and b,
if i checked one item in a then corresponding values should display in b and if i checked other item in a then corresponding values should add to exixting items in b checkbox list.
Please Help Me to Solve It.

Comment: Does these two `CheckBox` have any relationship ?

Comment: ASP.NET or WinForms or wpf

Comment: yes based on a checkbox i want to populate b checkbox problem is i want to check 2 items in a soo for those 2 items i want to populate b items

Comment: it is asp.net   i was reffered to use array list how can i use it to add  items in array list and finally populate in checkbox list b.

Answer (score 0):

use checkbox postback get the checked value then control the visibility of b

example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx